# Docker & MySQL: No secrets are created with docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

My Docker container keeps restarting when running `docker-compose up -d`. When inspecting the logs with `docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps db`, I get the following error:

`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 37: "/run/secrets/db_mysql_root_pw": No such file or directory`

This probably means that no secrets are made. The output of `docker secret ls` also gives no secrets.

My docker-compose.yml file looks something like this (excluding port info etc.):

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER_FILE="/run/secrets/db_mysql_user"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE="/run/secrets/db_mysql_user_pw"
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE="/run/secrets/db_mysql_root_pw"
    secrets:
      - db_mysql_user
      - db_mysql_user_pw
      - db_mysql_root_pw
    volumes:
      - "./mysql-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
secrets:
  db_mysql_user:
    file: ./db_mysql_user.txt
  db_mysql_user_pw:
    file: ./db_mysql_user_pw.txt
  db_mysql_root_pw:
    file: ./db_mysql_root_pw.txt
```

In the same directory I have the 3 text files which simply contain the values for the environment variables. e.g. `db_mysql_user_pw.txt` contains `password`.

I am running Linux containers on a Windows host.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty dumb but changing

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_USER_FILE="/run/secrets/db_mysql_user"
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE="/run/secrets/db_mysql_user_pw"
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE="/run/secrets/db_mysql_root_pw"
```

to

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/db_mysql_user
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_mysql_user_pw
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_mysql_root_pw
```

made it work. I still don't know why I cannot see the secrets with `docker secret ls` though.

Comment: `docker secret` handles docker swarm secrets. Modern docker-compose, on the other hand, supports non-swarm secrets - this doesn't seem to be a standard docker feature.